# Replacing broken PVC pipe

Tags: pvc

I want to remove what is left of the pipe. The pipe just takes liquid from the heater to the sewer. Part of the pipe is screwed into the heater, as you can see.
 [image: I broke this pipe in a bad spot. How can I remove what is left of the pipe?]

Comment: Isn't it just screwed in? Push something like a very wide screwdriver into the broken end and unscrew it.

Comment: Thank you. BTW, do you think in this case it is a better idea to just glue the pipe?

Comment: It's certainly a bad idea to just glue the broken pipe back together. The question you must ask yourself is: How often do you want to repair this plumbing? Take it all apart and rebuild it properly, then you won't have to coma back again and again.

Comment: BTW after rebuilding, you should try to figure out why it snapped off, and maybe add a bracket or other support to take the stress off the pipe.

Answer (score 4):

Extractor tool, like $5 at your local hardware store:

[image]